# Who listens to the DOM events (such as onclick) on HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm learning client-side JavaScript and I'm a little confused on how HTML elements listen to DOM events and execute the callback?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A page for you!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="text-field" value="" />
    <button id="submit-button">Submit me!</button>
    <script type="application/javascript">
      const textField = document.getElementById("text-field");
      const button = document.getElementById("submit-button");
      const showValue = () => {
        let inputValue = textField.value;
        alert(inputValue);
      };
      button.onclick = showValue;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For example, I did assign `showValue` to `button.onclick` property. but who sets up the listener and executes `button.onclick`?

I imagine there must be some JavaScript code somewhere and it would be like

```
const button.listenToOnclick = function() {
  // wait until user clicks
  if (clicked && button.onclick) {
    button.onclick();
  }
}
button.listenToOnClick(); // async and waits for the click to execute onclick
```

Is this code embedded in the HTML button tag?

Comment: Yes; the `onclick` attribute behavior is built into the DOM implementation of the browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers would be a good article if you're interested in some more specifics.

Comment: The `<button>` tag will listen for onClicks, it will then check the element for an `onClick`, it will also check for listeners on the button too, and using listeners is better then using `onclick` on the element,.   As this allows multiple listeners per element, not just one.

Comment: `button.onclick = showValue;` sets adds an "event handler" on the element directly, using its `onclick` attribute. When the `click` event happens on that particular object, the single specified function is called. A recommended alternative is to use an "event listener". See MDN for how these work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener (and maybe check out this post for some ideas about the difference: https://dillionmegida.com/p/inline-events-vs-add-event-listeners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every HTML element is natively an Object. Each one of these Objects when it is constructed has a set of properties that make it inherently an Object. The same way that you have .value on your text field inherent to its creation you have multiple other functions that are available to you such as .onClick.

When you attach a function to an event you are accessing this prebaked in functionality.

To answer your question the button itself is listening for the onClick function to fire. But the thing that is sending that information to the Button or to the DOM is the Window. The Window is an instance of your Javascript,HMTL, and CSS running in your browser.

So what happens is the window knows you have clicked and where you have clicked. It then sends that information down the dom and says "Is there anything there?" if there is, it then says "Was it listening to a click event?" if both of these conditions are met then the onClick event fires.

Comment: when you say the button itself is listening, is the `<button></button>` tag or more of the DOM object corresponding to it?

Comment: The tag is just a placeholder for the Button Object inside of the DOM. It functions the same way as if you were to order a cheeseburger. You say "I want a cheeseburger" and then the restaurant brings you one. In this case you are using HTML to say "I would like a button" then the DOM creates a button Object for you with all of the properties inherent to it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the entities you're looking for are our beloved browsers. Each browser have *[engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_engine)* that are responsible for executing JavaScript, rendering the layout, deal with user-DOM interactions, security issues and probably a lot more.

For example, Firefox uses the engine *Gecko* to render pages and the engine *SpiderMonkey* to deal with JavaScript. Chrome uses the engine *Blink* for rendering and *V8* for JavaScript (the engine that Node.js was originated from).